# `fork': Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan running `rails console` on Manjaro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, archlinux, manjaro

I've tried looking through plenty of posts on here already but I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. This is the output after running `rails console`, is this a Manjaro issue or am I missing some dependencies? Thanks!

```
/home/austin/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bundler-1.17.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:200: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
Running via Spring preloader in process 16510
Traceback (most recent call last):
/home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:175:in `fork': Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
    42: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    41: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    40: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
    39: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    38: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    37: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    36: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
    35: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
    34: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    33: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    32: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    31: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    30: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    29: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    28: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    27: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    26: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    25: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    24: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    23: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
    22: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `lookup'
    21: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `each'
    20: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `block in lookup'
    19: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `each'
    18: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    17: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    16: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    15: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    14: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    13: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    11: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    10: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
     9: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:3:in `<main>'
     8: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     7: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     6: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     5: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require'
     4: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:41:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
     1: from /home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/austin/cs362-coad-resources/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- irb (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/250.

Probably Bootsnap is overriding other load errors. Try to remove it and see what error you get, then you can fix it properly and return with Bootsnap.

Comment: Went through and tried that with no fix. The issue was using Ruby 2.7, used rvm to hop back to 2.6.5 and everything runs as intended now. Thanks for the response either way!